# R recover() stuck on "Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit "

Tags: r, debugging, recover

I'm considering using [`recover()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/recover.html) as an error option. but every time I hit an error, I am unable to do any interactive debugging because it just keeps telling me `Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit` no matter what I do (I have commented in full everything that I type after the error occurs):

```
> options(error = recover)
> foo <- function() {x <- "foo"; stop(x)}
> foo()
Error in foo() : foo

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: foo()

### I type '1'
Selection: 1
Called from: top level 
Browse[1]> 

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: foo()

### I type 'x'
Selection: x
Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit

### I type 'objects()'
Selection: objects()
Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit

### I type '0'
Selection: 0

### Recover exits and R returns to normal
```

The only thing it responds to appears to be '0' to exit `recover()`. Note that I did not press enter at `Browse[1]>` - it is simply skipped over and I don't get the chance to input anything.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using `R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)` with Revolution R Enterprise IDE (x64) 7.0.0 under Windows 8.1

### Edit

I think this is a problem to do with Revolution R IDE, as I tried this with the default RGui console and I could type stuff at `Browse[1]>` and therefore use `recover` successfully. If anyone with experience of Revolution R IDE has any further insight on this, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: At the prompt `Browse[1]>`, did you hit "return"? If so, the debugger returns to the frame number selection.

Comment: @user1981275 No! That's the thing - at `Browse[1]` I don't get the chance to hit anything! It simply skips to `Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've submitted a bug report to Revolution Analytics, and so far this has been their reply:

> Milo,
>
> Thanks for the report. As I indicated, a defect has been filed with the development team. Running this code through the console works as expected and that only through the script window does it fail. I am closing the support ticket as there is no decision when this will be address.
>
> Regards,
>
> Brian Pinkney
>
> Manager, Revolution Analytics Technical Support

I will update if they contact me again.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `options(error = recover)` you are stopping everything to have access to the entire call stack. If you had a function that would have a longer rout, this would be more apparent. In your case, when you enter 1, you go into the function `foo` at the time of evaluation. This function holds an object called `x` with the values of `"foo"` as demonstrated below.

```
> foo()
Error in foo() : foo

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: foo()

Selection: 1
Called from: top level 
Browse[1]> ls()
[1] "x"
Browse[1]> x
[1] "foo"
```

If you're done browsing in the current call (in your case under number 1), you can exit to the "menu" by pressing enter or calling `c` (see `?browser`).

*EDIT*

Here's a bit longer example that may show you what `recover` does (basically a menu giving you access to called functions and their objects).

```
> foo <- function(x) {
+   obj1 <- "object in foo"
+   foo2 <- function(y) {
+     obj2 <- "object in foo2"
+     stop()
+   }
+   foo2(x)
+ }
> 
> foo(letters)
Error in foo2(x) : 

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: foo(letters)
2: #7: foo2(x)

Selection: 1 # go into function foo()
Called from: top level 
Browse[1]> ls()
[1] "foo2" "obj1" "x"   
Browse[1]> obj1
[1] "object in foo"
Browse[1]>  # i hit enter here

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: foo(letters)
2: #7: foo2(x)

Selection: 2 # go into function foo2()
Called from: foo(letters)
Browse[1]> ls()
[1] "obj2" "y"   
Browse[1]> obj2
[1] "object in foo2"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not given the opportunity to type anything at `Browse[1]>`. I'm simply sent to the the frame selector again. So I only ever get to type anything after seeing `Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit`

Comment: @MiloChen, can you reproduce this in "raw" R?

Comment: Thanks, Roman. I think this is a problem to do with Revolution R IDE, as I tried this with the default RGui console and I could type stuff at `Browse[1]>` and therefore use `recover` successfully. If anyone with experience of Revolution R IDE has any further insight on this, I'd be most grateful.